# Display fieldset data to center of page

Tags: html, css

Am trying to make my fieldset data to be at center of the page but it displays in my page towards left. It displays fine fiddle, http://fiddle.jshell.net/8SuLK/ but not displaying to center of page in browser. How to go about.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check my answer and see how you can center elements in two different ways :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove position from fieldset and try like this: **[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8SuLK/2/)**

CSS:

```
fieldset {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ffc;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
   width:70%;
    border: 2px groove threedface;
}
```

Comment: am not able to open fiddle demo which you have shared

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to have your fieldset positioned as fixed then you can center it in two ways.

1) Setting a width to your fieldset and add auto to its margin property.

**EXAMPLE**

```
fieldset {
border-radius: 10px;
background: #ffc;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 20px;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
border: 2px groove threedface;
width:75%;
}
```

**DEMO** http://fiddle.jshell.net/8SuLK/3/

2) Adding a wrapper to your fieldset and set it as text-align:center; and then set display:inline-block; to the fieldset.

**EXAMPLE**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <fieldset>
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" />
        <label>Middle Name:</label>
            <input type="text" />
        <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" />
        <label>Date of Birth:</label>
            <input type="date" />
    </fieldset>
</div>

.wrapper{text-align:center;}

fieldset {
border-radius: 10px;
background: #ffc;
margin: 20px;
padding: 20px;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
display:inline-block;
border: 2px groove threedface;
}
```

**DEMO** http://fiddle.jshell.net/8SuLK/4/

PS. Just a reminder in your jsfiddle you can see the syntax highlighter showing in red the syntax errors. In your case the last closing tag, `</fieldset>` was in red because each input tag wasn't closed. Remember the right syntax for input is `<input type="text" />`.

Furthermore it's good practice to add the id to each input `<input type="text" id="firstname" />` and then specify what the label is for like `<label for="firstname">First Name</label>`